# Raspberry pi Zero W SSH through USB, appears as ethernet device on ubuntu but can't SSH

Tags: raspbian, networking, usb, ssh

I've followed several tutorials on how to setup SSH through USB for my raspberry pi zero w. I've followed https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2016/06/connect-raspberry-pi-zero-usb-cable-ssh/ and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xj3MPmJhAPU which says the same things.

My raspberry pi zero W with raspbian appears on the wired connections on Ubuntu, and I can even connect to it. I activated it with ON and it displays connecting forever.

Look at my `ifconfig` on my laptop:

```
enp0s20f0u1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5c6d:6621:10ce:3c88  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1e:df:87:0b:23:bf  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 368  bytes 17203 (17.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 110  bytes 21428 (21.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Looks like my rasberry pi appears on my ubuntu with the ipv6 `fe80::5c6d:6621:10ce:3c88`. I even found out how to connect through ipv6 on ssh:

```
ssh -6 pi@fe80::5c6d:6621:10ce:3c88%enp0s20f0u1
```

but I always get **connection refused**.

Does anybody have any idea of how to do it?

**UPDATE**: I also tried https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/73665/74564 with no success. I see no IP information on `ifconfig` or the network GUI manager

**UPDATE**: I had to add an IP to the raspberry pi ethernet device. This answer is complete: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/83647/74564

Comment: as a sanity check, is SSH enabled? Rasbian has it disabled by default (or at least at my last install it was).

Comment: @bashCypher yes it was. I found a way, see the update