# Is it possible to upgrade Raspian without running it on a Pi?

Tags: raspbian, image

I would like to use my Linux host to update and upgrade a Raspian image. Can this be done?

I know you can mount the image and make permanent changes, see e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/13138/101680

The reason I want to do this is I have a Pi Zero that won't boot. I suspect a bug in Raspian Buster and would like to experiment with the latest changes ([Pi Zero USB On The Go cannot connect](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108889/101680))

Comment: You could run it inside of a Docker container with QEMU: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109524/107831

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if I were doing work with a Pi Zero, I'd seriously consider having a Pi 3 B+ or Pi 4 with monitor and keyboard available.  If monitor and keyboard are a constraint, you could still use VNC from your Linux system.

Comment: @tttapa Your comment would make a great answer if you included how to save the changed container into a new Raspbian image.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Qemu User Emulation to accomplish this via `chroot`. Its a similar sort of setup to debootsrapping a foreign arch but you'll already have the OS installed.

This assumes your host is Debian based - i'd assume the Qemu stuff is available on other distros though.

Important steps from the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/QemuUserEmulation)

`sudo apt-get install qemu binfmt-support qemu-user-static`

Mount your Pi SD card somewhere on your linux host

`mkdir /tmp/pizero`
`sudo mount /dev/mmcblks0p1 /tmp/pizero` (or whatever it is called on your system)

Copy the Qemu binary onto the pi SD card (can be deleted when you've finished) - might not need to do this anymore though.
`cp /usr/bin/qemu-arm-static /tmp/pizero/usr/bin`

Chroot into the Pi and you can then treat it as if it was running natively.
`sudo chroot /tmp/pizero`

and you should end up as root on the Pi and able to run apt and stuff against the Pi FS.

Comment: I've not tried this, but the referenced link does not seem to cover saving the changed Raspbian image.

Comment: The changes you make whilst the card is mounted on the host will persist. When you have finished exit the `chroot` by typing `exit` and `sudo umount /dev/mmcblkp01` (or whatever it is) to unmount the volume and then `sudo sync` to write back any lingering changes. You can then eject the SD card.