# Model B+ V1.2 not found in network after headless installation

Tags: raspbian, headless

I copied the latest (April 18th) Raspbian lite image to a 32 GB SD card with Imager. Then I created an empty ssh file and the wpa_supplicant.conf file with ssid and psk as I use them on my laptop. After booting the pi I tried to ping (from Mac or Linux) it but:

ping: cannot resolve pi@raspberrypi.local: Unknown host

Here the file:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
 ssid="myNet"
 psk="xxx"
}
```

What could be missing? Thanks for any help

Comment: You should not include the user id in the ping. Try `ping raspberrypi.local`.

Comment: `Then I created an ssh folder` 0 you mean empty **file**? I wonder if having a folder would actually work? `and the wpa_supplicant.conf file with said and psk as I use them on my laptop` - in the correct format, right?

Comment: Sorry, I created an empty ssh file (touch /Volumes/boot/ssh)

And removing pi@ didn't help

Comment: Does the router show the Pi connected? Did you put the country code in the wpa_supplicant file?  It may be best if you show the file here with the SSID and password replaced with x - leave all quotes etc as is and edit the question using the code option so we can see the actual layout please. Are you trying to connect from a Mac, PC or Linux box?

Comment: The pi doesn't show up in the router. Here the file:
`ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=DE

network={
 ssid="myNet"
 psk="xxx"
}`

The file has the correct line breaks as in [https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md]

Comment: If you booted the RasPi with `/boot/ssh` and then look afterwards into that directory, is `/boot/ssh` still there? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that model B+ V 1.2 doesn't have a WIFI chip

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

If you can log on to the Pi, try executing this command:

```
rfkill list all
```

You may see something like this:

> 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
>
> ```
>   Soft blocked: yes
>
>   Hard blocked: no
> ```
>
> 1: hci0: Bluetooth
>
> ```
>   Soft blocked: yes
>
>   Hard blocked: no
> ```

A hard block is caused by a hardware switch, which I don't think the Pi has. A soft block can be removed with:

```
rfkill unblock wifi
```

This worked for me, even after a reboot. I got the hint from https://askubuntu.com/questions/566799/wifi-soft-blocked-by-rfkill-on-startup

Comment: As you can read in the title, the OP has a headless installation, so he cannot do what you suggested.

Comment: @Ingo It is possible to edit the OS image. See e.g. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109750/101680